# Plot the regression line of the machine learning prediction model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I would like to plot the regression line of the machine learning model on the data scatter plot as shown below:

[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

Firstly, take any two dependent variables and split the data to train and test the model.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_train = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
GradientBoostingRegressor().fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

Comment: If you want to make a 2D plot, you can use only one input feature and the target variable.

Answer (score 2):

After training model, predict its output on the input range, and plot it as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
a, b = 10, 2
features = np.random.randn(1000, 1)
labels  = a * (features + np.random.randn(*features.shape)) + (b + np.random.randn(*features.shape))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
model = GradientBoostingRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
x_range = np.linspace(features.min()-0.5, features.max() + 0.5, 1000)
plt.scatter(features, labels, alpha=0.1)
plt.plot(x_range, model.predict(x_range.reshape(-1, 1)), label="GradientBoostingRegressor()",
          linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel("Features")
plt.ylabel("Label")
plt.title("Title Here")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```